# Transform string format whith month into timestamp in datastage

Tags: datastage

I want transform the string
Thu, 21 Jan 2021 09:48:38 +0100
in timestamp format "%yyyy-%mm-%dd %hh.%nn.%ss.6"

how to do?

Thank you

Comment: Please use backtick for formating code(format), and provide more details, some example, you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [StringToTimestamp](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.parjob.dev.doc/topics/r_deeref_Type_Conversion_Functions.html) function and the other type conversion functions in DataStage.

You could also work with string manipulation first.
Note that you have not provided the information about the fraction of the second yet.